# Create a new MySQL stored procedure in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I use the [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) library for communicating with a database. It supports calling stored procedures. Does somebody know if this same library, or another npm package, can CREATE stored procedures? This seems impossible to do.

#### Extra information

What I essentially want to do, is creating a reset script for my database, deleting all tables and views. If I can do this without stored procedure, fine! For now, a stored procedure was needed for the IF-clause.

This is what I got:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS drop_all_tables;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_tables()
BEGIN
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
  SET @tables = NULL;
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @tables
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'my_database'
    AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
  IF @tables IS NOT NULL THEN BEGIN
    SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END; END IF;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
CALL drop_all_tables();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS drop_all_tables;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS drop_all_views;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_views()
BEGIN
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
  SET @views = NULL;
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @views
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'my_database'
    AND table_type = 'VIEW';
  IF @views IS NOT NULL THEN BEGIN
    SET @views = CONCAT('DROP VIEW ', @views);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @views;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END; END IF;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
CALL drop_all_views();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS drop_all_views;
```

Comment: But why you want to create procedure via node ?

Comment: I want to remove all tables, and I need a stored procedure for that. I don't want it permanently though, so I create and delete it. I'll provide more info in the question.

Comment: Can you not use an ORM, like sequelize.
That could very well streamline your workflow with migrations

Comment: Have you tried using ```mysql```?

Comment: @Wainage, this would require the availability of the mysql command, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Shivam, I'm working with an existing system, switching to sequelize is not an option.

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't think so. I has been a while...